# What's the French word for "What" if it's the subject in an interrogative sentence? Like in "What did that to you?" That isn't "qu'est ce qui"

Tags: grammaire, traduction, questions, pronoms-interrogatifs

In French, is there a word for "What" like in "What did that to you"? In the sentence "What's happening?" "What" is often translated as "qu'est qui" and qu'est-il" why is this? And does this apply to questions that aren't "What's happening"? I don't understand how "qu'est-il" or "qu'est qui" can translate to "what" since "qu'est-ce qui" translates to "what is it that".

Comment: Then how would you say "what did that to you" in French?

Comment: Also why is the t-il necessary?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, maybe you should reformulate your question after you have looked a litlle into "*est-ce que*". Numerous posts on [*est-ce que*](http://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=est-ce%20que) on French Language and maybe [this page](http://www.french-linguistics.co.uk/grammar/questions.shtml) on how to ask questions in French.

Comment: "What" is just "*que*". "What's happening?" → *Que se passe-t-il ?* or *Qu'est-ce ce qui se passe* ? "What did that do to you?" →  *Qu'est-ce qui t'a fait ça?* The *est-ce que* construction is the part of the verb that bears the interrogation in "*est-ce que* questions" and the fist *que* is subject of *être*.

Comment: is "que cela t'a-t-il fait?" correct or no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Qu'est-ce qui” does not translate to “what is it that”. It translates to “what”. “Est-ce que” is a fixed idiom, it's one of the three ways of formulating a question:

- formal: verb-subject inversion, e.g. “Qu'as-tu fait ?”
- neutral: “est-ce que”, e.g. “Qu'est-ce que tu as fait ?”
- informal: same word order as a positive statement, e.g. “Tu as fait quoi ?” (for a yes/no question, the fact that the sentence is a question is only conveyed by intonation)

The word corresponding to *what* is either *quoi* or *que*. In simple cases, it's *que* when the interrogative pronoun comes before the verb and *quoi* when it comes after. There are many exceptions, see your grammar books or [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quoi#Variantes) for more detailed rules.

When the interrogative pronoun is the subject of the sentence, you can use *qui* if it stands for a person, but not if it stands for a thing. There is no neutral subject interrogative pronoun, you need to use “que'est-ce qui”. For example, “What did that to you?” = “Qu'est-ce qui t'a fait ça ?” As you can see, “qu'est-ce qui” *is* the translation of *what* when it's the subject of the sentence.

Comment: In all of those sentences, *what* is the object of the verb. OP wanted to know what interrogative word to use when *what* is the inanimate subject of a question. Think about it: as interrogative pronouns, *que* and *qu'est-ce que* and *quoi* can only be used as objects, both animate and inanimate.

Comment: @Eauquidort Oh, yes, good point, I added that.