# Que comme sujet dans la langue littéraire

Tags: questions, pronoms-interrogatifs, que

Est-ce qu'il est possible d'utiliser « que » comme sujet dans une phrase au lieu de  « Qu'est-ce qui », dans un contexte littéraire ? Par exemple :

> Que vous y intéressa ?

au lieu de

> Qu'est-ce qui vous y a intéressé ?

Comment: Ça ne marche pas, ou plus. "Que vous y intéressa?" ne s'utilise pas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "que" be an interrogative subject pronoun?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21499/can-que-be-an-interrogative-subject-pronoun)

Comment: Ou ça aussi : https://french.stackexchange.com/q/19541/1893

Comment: ***Que** lui avez-vous trouvé d'intéressant ?* or ***Qu**'y a-t-il d'intéressant pour vous ?*

Comment: @jlliagre Dans votre première réponse, vous utilisez un passé composé plutôt que le passé simple de la première question. J'ai remarqué dans d'autre cas que nous utilisons le passé composé plus facilement que le passé simple, parfois en fonction de la personne du sujet. Ce phénomène a-t'il un nom?

Comment: @Frank Je ne sais pas quel nom particulier cette préférence peut avoir, mais la substitution du passé simple par le passé composé est une évolution du français qui a débuté dès le XIIᵉ siècle, rien de très nouveau donc.

Comment: « Que m’importe » est une expression encore en usage (quoique appartenant à un registre de langue plutôt soutenu). Elle se trouve entre autres dans Le Cid de Corneille ([acte II](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Le_Cid/%C3%89dition_Ginn/Acte_II), scène 2) ou dans Britannicus de Racine ([acte I](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Britannicus_(%C3%A9ditions_Didot,_1854)/Acte_I), scène 1).

Comment: Que nenni! Bannissez promptement ce mésusage vieilli, de la langue française moderne, fut-elle littéraire.
Comme pour toute règle d'airain, il y a évidement des exceptions pour certaines expressions.

Comment: Je crois que lien donné par @livresque fournit une réponse incorrecte : "In the following question : 
Mais que sont ces cercles rouges sur le dos de Michael Phelps ?
que is the subject of sont" - le sujet est "ces cercles rouges". "que" peut s'utiliser comme attribut mais, ici, la question porte sur son utilisation comme sujet.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne trouve aucun exemple où *que* ait fonction de sujet.

Dans *Qu'est-ce qui a changé?*, le pronom *qu(e)* est attribut du groupe sujet: le pronom *ce* complété par la relative *qui a changé*.

Dans *Que m'importe?* ou *Que me chaut?*, *que* a fonction d'adverbe: il est remplaçable par *combien*.
Le sujet est alors sous-entendu. Explicité, nous aurions p. ex. *Il se démet, qu'importe? Que valut son appui, que me chaut cette noise?*